# Creating a validator that will try to parse GeoJSON from a TextFormField

Tags: json, flutter, dart, geojson

I am trying to create a widget that allows users to dump a GeoJSON string into the text field, which will be saved eventually as a GeoJsonLine. I am currently trying to get some validation logic working that will check that the string can be parsed as GeoJSON (rather than just pure JSON, as I hope this will save me some steps). I am somewhat new to asynchronous programming, and am having a hard time conceptualizing how to handle the Future type that gets returned by the function provided by the geojson.dart package.

I would like the validator of the TextFormField widget to handle three distinct scenarios:

1. There is no text entered
2. There is text entered, but it cannot be parsed as GeoJSON
3. The text is a valid GeoJSON string

An example of the code I am trying to get working:

```
import 'package:geojson/geojson.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'

//An example GeoJSON string that should parse cleanly
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
          "type": "LineString",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              -114.84214782714844,
              50.80520247265613
            ],
            [
              -114.84240531921385,
              50.806883927982305
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }

Future<void> checkGeoJson(String? input, int check) async {
    try {
      String strInput = input.toString();
      final blob = await featuresFromGeoJson(strInput);
      check = 44; //arbitrary number that allows me to check where the issue is
    } catch (e) {
      print('parse error');
      check = 55; //see above comment
    }
  }

...//More involved widget tree above this code block
TextFormField(
    controller: trackController,
    validator: (value) {
    int parseSuccessful = 11; //if everything goes well, then 11 should be printed
    checkGeoJson(value, parseSuccessful); 
    //run the parse here, so that parseSuccessful is already set?
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) { //no text entered case
        print(parseSuccessful);
        return 'Please enter some text';
    } else if (parseSuccessful == 55) { //text entered, invalid GeoJSON
        print(parseSuccessful);
        return 'Text is not valid GeoJSON';
    } else { //Text entered and valid GeoJSON
        print(parseSuccessful);
        return 'Valid JSON';
    }
 }),
```

The issue I am having is that if I enter "test" into the form, the console logs a unhandled ParseErrorException, but the validator returns 'Valid JSON' to the TextFormField. How do I route this error to get the correct return value? The error message and console output are below.

```
flutter: Error: [FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
test
^
, #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseKeywordPrefix (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:987:44)
#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseFalse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:949:14)
#3      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:862:22)
#4      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)
#5      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
#6      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:216:41)
#7      GeoJson._processFeatures (package:geojson/src/geojson.dart:453:26)
#8      GeoJson._processFeaturesIso (package:geojson/src/geojson.dart:437:5)
#9      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:300:17)
#10     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
]
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Instance of 'ParseErrorException'
#0      GeoJson._parse.<anonymous closure> (package:geojson/src/geojson.dart:200:7)
#1      Iso.run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:iso/src/iso.dart:80:17)
#2      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1586:10)
#3      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
#4      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
#5      _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:774:19)
#6      _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:648:7)
#7      _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:596:5)
#8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
```

Answer (score 1):

First in your validator, the `parseSuccessful` will always be 11 because you're not passing the memory address of `parseSuccessful` to  `checkGeoJson` function

```
validator: (value) {
    int parseSuccessful = 11; //if everything goes well, then 11 should be printed
    checkGeoJson(value, parseSuccessful); 
    //run the parse here, so that parseSuccessful is already set?
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) { //no text entered case
        print(parseSuccessful);
        return 'Please enter some text';
    } else if (parseSuccessful == 55) { //text entered, invalid GeoJSON
        print(parseSuccessful);
        return 'Text is not valid GeoJSON';
    } else { //Text entered and valid GeoJSON
        print(parseSuccessful);
        return 'Valid JSON';
    }
```

And I think the better to do what you want is to check the value asynchronously in the `onChanged` field, then change the `errorText` when the result has come.

Here's a little example:

```
class GeoTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  GeoTextField({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GeoTextField> createState() => _GeoTextFieldState();
}

class _GeoTextFieldState extends State<GeoTextField> {
  String? errorText;
  Timer? _debounce;

  featuresFromGeoJson(String value) {
    // ...
  }

  Future<void> checkGeoJson(String value) async {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        errorText = 'Please enter some text';
      });
      return;
    }
    // debounce
    if (_debounce?.isActive ?? false) _debounce?.cancel();
    _debounce = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () async {
      try {
        // check GeoJSON validation
        await featuresFromGeoJson(value);
      } catch (e) {
        setState(() {
          errorText = "Text is not valid GeoJSON";
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _debounce?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: TextFormField(
        onChanged: (value) => checkGeoJson(value),
        decoration: InputDecoration(errorText: errorText),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I copied your code and tried to run it, but so far I am only getting an error when the field is cleared after putting some text in, and no error is returned when I have an invalid json string (eg. "test") in the field. I don't know if this matters, but I am calling the GeoTextField widget in a StatefulWidget in main.dart. Is there a reason why using a validator wouldn't work? Is it just tricky to get a validator to work with an async function?